# How can I create a dynamic web.sitemap?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a Dynamic Web.Sitemap, By dynamic I mean that file should be editable and I want to be able to edit it's nodes from my code.
I have tried this on a button's click event.

```
SiteMapNode smRoot = SiteMap.RootNode;
SiteMapNode smNode = new 
           SiteMapNode(smRoot.Provider, "Key", "~/Default.aspx", "Default");
smRoot.ChildNodes.Add(smNode);
```

But got an error `Collection is read-only.` at last line.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
public void GetSiteMap(List<string> MyList)
{
    /// Add namespace:
    ///using System.Xml;
    ///using System.Data;
    ///using System.Xml.Serialization;

    String MyHome = "http://www.mysite.com" ;//Create Absolute url start.

    // create DataSet and DataTable if needed, or use List Array only
   /*
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        foreach (var array in MyList)
        {
            DT.Rows.Add(array);
        }

    */
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();// create XML Documents
    XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);// Create the head element
    doc.AppendChild(dec);

    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("urlset");// Create the root element with attributes

    root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    root.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
    doc.AppendChild(root);

    //foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)// if use DataTable or
    foreach (var array in MyList)// if use List only
    {
        XmlElement MyUrl = doc.CreateElement("url");//create child node for root node

        XmlElement Loc = doc.CreateElement("loc");//create child node for MyUrl node
        XmlElement Freq = doc.CreateElement("changefreq");//create child node for MyUrl node
        XmlElement Pri = doc.CreateElement("priority");//create child node for MyUrl node

        Loc.InnerText = MyHome + "/" + array;//set value for 1. child node  Loc node
        Freq.InnerText = "daily";//set value for 1. child node-Freq node
        Pri.InnerText = "0.85";//set value for 1. child node-Pri node

        MyUrl.AppendChild(Loc); //add child Loc node to MyUrl node
        MyUrl.AppendChild(Freq);//add child Freq node to MyUrl node
        MyUrl.AppendChild(Pri);//add child Pri node to MyUrl node


        root.AppendChild(MyUrl);//add child MyUrl node to root node
    }


    Response.Clear();
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    xs.Serialize(Response.Output, doc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Call this void on PageLoad()

:)